# IMO-2012 Problem 6 (Dušan Djukić, Serbia)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

**IMO-2012 Problem 6 (Dušan Djukić, Serbia)**

Find all positive integers ( n ) for which there exist non-negative integers ${a_1}$, $a_2 $, $ \dots $, $ a_n $ such that 
\[ \frac1{2^{a_1}}+\frac1{2^{a_2}}+\cdots+\frac1{2^{a_n}}=\frac1{3^{a_1}}+\frac2{3^{a_2}}+\cdots+\frac{n}{3^{a_n}}=1.\]

Comment: See http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2737435.

Answer (score 3):

For reasons that will become clearer later, I will reformulate the problem as finding a suitable set of pairs $A(n)=\{(1,a_1),(2,a_2),\ldots,(N,a_N)\}$.

---

This type of problem is usually solved in two steps:

1. Some suitable use of divisibility in order to prove that some values of $N$ are impossible;
2. An algorithmic construction for the remaining values of $N$.

The first part is the easiest! Get the rightmost equality, multiply by $3^M$ big enough in order to clear all denominators; let $b_i=M-a_i$, then we have something like

$$1 \cdot 3^{b_1} + 2 \cdot 3^{b_2} + 3 \cdot 3^{b_3}+ \ldots + 1 \cdot 3^{b_n} = 3^M$$

Looking at it modulo 2, we have $3^b_i \equiv 1$ and then $1 + 2 + \ldots + N \equiv 1$

We will now split it in two cases:

- $N$ even, $N=2x$. Then we have $1+3+ \ldots + (2x-1) \equiv 1$, in other words we have $x$ odd, and then $N=4k+2$
- $N$ odd, $N=2x-1$. Then we have $1+3+ \ldots + (2x-1) \equiv 1$, in other words we have $x$ odd, and then $N=4k+1$

Summarizing: the possible values of $N$ can be only those $4k+1$ or $4k+2$.

This was the part 1.

---

In order to solve the part 2, we need to generate solutions for the cases $N=4k+1$ and $N=4k+2$.

Here, the idea is to make a transition from N to N+12. In other words, we want to find solutions for numbers in the forms $12k+1, 12k+2, 12k+5, 12k+6, 12k+9, 12k+10$.

---

Start with some minor examples to serve as base cases:

- n= 1: $\{(1,0)\}$
- n= 2: $\{(1,1),(2,1)\}$
- n= 5: $\{(1,2),(2,2),(3,3),(4,3),(5,3)\}$
- n= 6: $\{(1,2),(2,2),(3,4),(4,3),(5,3),(6,4)\}$
- n= 9: $\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,2),(4,4),(5,4),(6,4),(7,4),(8,4),(9,4)\}$
- n=10: $\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,2),(4,4),(5,5),(6,4),(7,4),(8,4),(9,4), (10,5)\}$

---

Now we will delineate our algorithmic step!

Our main tool for it is that single operation below, we will call it a *split*. It is more or less like this:

If where $i+j=3K$, then

$$1 \cdot 2^{-a_K} = 1 \cdot 2^{-(a_K+1)} + 1 \cdot 2^{-(a_K+1)}$$

and

$$K \cdot 3^{-a_K} = i \cdot 3^{-(a_K+1)} + j \cdot 3^{-(a_K+1)}$$

That way, the split operation consists in replacing the pair $\{(K,a_K)\}$ by $\{(i,a_k+1),(j,a_k+1)\}$ for $i+j=3K$.

Yes, it can erase the pair $(k,a_k)$ of our set, and we don't want such a "destructive update". But that hurdle can be circumvented if we make $i=k$; in other words, we change the pair $\{(k,a_k)\}$ by $\{(k,a_k+1),(2k,a_k+1)\}$, effectively replacing the pair $k$ and creating the pair of $2k$.

That way, the split operation doesn't change the sums of our hypothesis; and by using judiciously the splits, we can guarrantee no pair is removed completely, only substituted or created. We only need to control the creation in order it doesn't explode the $N+12$ limit.

---

Our heuristics will work this way:

- Suppose we have solved the problem for a certain $N$. We then need to solve it for $N+12$, by creating the pairs for the set $S = \{N+1, N+2, \ldots, N+12\}$.
- The even guys can be obtained by splitting them via $\{(k,a_k)\} \rightarrow \{(k,a_k+1),(2k,a_k+1)\}$
- The odd guys can be grouped in pairs summing a multiple of 12 each; by splitting a suitable guy two times, they can be generated the pairs in one step.

---

I will start with an example: from $A(1)$ we want to generate $A(13)$. We will, in each step, add the least guy not created until now.

- 1 was created (by hypothesis)
- 2 was not created

  - 2 is even, and its half, 1, was created before; split that guy!
  - $\{(1,0)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,1)\}$ (*)
- 3 was not created

  - 3 is odd, and its pair will be 9; we will create both
  - $3+9 = 12 = 3 \cdot 4$
  - Then, we non-destructively update 2 in order to generate 4, and from this 4 we destructively generate 3 and 9.
  - Indeed, $\{(1,1), (2,1)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,2), (4,2)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (9,3)\}$
  - You could just ask here, "but we destroyed 4! Why didn't you keep it?". Well, you could keep it if you liked the idea, but that isn't necessary, because it will be inductively generated in a future step. Namely...
- 4 was not created

  - 4 is even, and its half, 2, was created. Split!
  - $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (9,3)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,3), (3,3),(4,3), (9,3)\}$
- 5 was not created

  - 5 is odd, and its pair is 7
  - $5+7=12= 3 \cdot 4$; again, we non-destructively split 2 in order to generate 4, and destructively split 4 in order to generate 5 and 7;
  - $\{(1,1), (2,3), (3,3), (4,3), (9,3)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,4), (3,3), (4,3), (4,4), (9,3)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,4), (3,3), (4,3), (5,5),(7,5),(9,3)\} $
- 6 was not created

  - 6 is even, and its half, 3, was already created; split!
  - $ \{(1,1), (2,4), (3,3), (4,3), (5,5),(7,5),(9,3)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,3), (5,5), (6,4), (7,5),(9,3)\} $
- 7 was created; skip to next!
- 8 was not created

  - 8 is even, and its half, 4, was already created; split!
  - $\{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,3), (5,5), (6,4), (7,5),(9,3)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,4), (5,5), (6,4), (7,5), (8,4),(9,3)\}$ (*)
- 9 was created; skip to next!
- 10 was not created

  - 10 is even, and its half, 5, was already created; split!
  - $\{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,4), (5,5), (6,4), (7,5), (8,4),(9,3)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,4), (5,6), (6,4), (7,5), (8,4),(9,3), (10,6)\} $ (*)
- 11 was not created

  - 11 is odd, and its pair will be 13; we will create both
  - $11+13=24 = 3 \cdot 8$
  - Then, we non-destructively split 4 in order to generate 8, and destructively split 8 in order to generate 11 and 13
  - $\{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,4), (5,6), (6,4), (7,5), (8,4),(9,3), (10,6)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,4), (7,5), (8,4),(9,3),(10,6), (11,6), (13,6)\} $
- 12 was not created

  - 12 was even, and its half, 6, was created; split!
  - $\{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,4), (7,5), (8,4),(9,3),(10,6), (11,6), (13,6)\} \rightarrow \{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,5), (7,5), (8,4),(9,3),(10,6), (11,6), (12,5), (13,6)\}$

And our set $A(13)$ is done! $A(13) = \{(1,1), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,5), (7,5), (8,4),(9,3),(10,6), (11,6), (12,5), (13,6)\}$

(Incidentally, note that we produced solutions for 2, 9 and 10)

---

Now we need to formalize our algorithm. Let us make an induction in $k$ such that we have solutions for all numbers $N \in \{12k+1, 12k+2, 12k+5, 12k+6, 12k+9, 12k+10\}$. The step is to build solutions for $N \in \{12k+13, 12k+14, 12k+17, 12k+18, 12k+21, 12k+22\}$ respectively.

I will exemplify the algorithm for $12k+5 \rightarrow 12k+17$ (the others are similar).

First, we need to group the odd guys in the group $\{12k+6, 12k+7, 12k+8, 12k+9, 12k+10, 12k+11, 12k+12, 12k+13, 12k+14, 12k+15, 12k+16, 12k+17\}$, in pairs summing a multiple of 12 - namely, $\{12k+7, 12k+17\} \cup \{12k+9, 12k+15\} \cup \{12k+11, 12k+13\} \cup \{12k+6, 12k+8, 12k+10, 12k+12, 12k+14, 12k+16\}$

Then we alternate between the even guys and the odd guys.

Here we start with the smallest, an even guy: $12k+6$ can be obtained by splitting its half, $6k+3$. That way, we replace $\{(6k+3,M)\}$ with $\{(6k+3,M+1), (12k+6,M+1)\}$.

The next will be the pair $\{12k+7, 12k+17\}$; they sum $24k+24 = 3 \cdot 4 \cdot (2k+2)$; then we need to split $2 \cdot (2k+2)$ and after it destructively split $4 \cdot (2k+2)$:

$\{(2 \cdot (2k+2),M)\} \rightarrow \{(2 \cdot (2k+2),M+1),(4 \cdot (2k+2),M+1)\} \rightarrow \{(2 \cdot (2k+2),M+1),(12k+7,M+2),(12k+17,M+2)\}$

Then we follow the steps in that same way:

- If the number we want to fill is even $(2m)$, split its half: $\{(m,k)\} \rightarrow \{(m,k+1), (2m, k+1)\}$
- If the number we want to fill is odd, associate it with the one not filled yet such that they sum a multiple of 12; let it be $u+v=24k+12r$ that sum. Then we split $(4k+2r)$: $\{(4k+2r,l)\} \rightarrow \{(4k+2r,l+1),(8k+4r,l+1)\} \rightarrow \{(4k+2r,l+1), (u,l+2), (v,l+2)\}$

And it ends our algorithm!